# How can I make my header mobile responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mobile-website

Can you please help me with making my existing header responsive? I've tried a lot, but nothing worked... Here is the HTML Code:

```
<header>
        <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="./img/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
            <h4 class="logo">CVaS</h4>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="one.html">1. Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="two.html">2. Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="three.html">3. Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

And here is the CSS Code:

```
    body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    height: 10vh;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo-container,
.nav-links {
    display: flex;
}

.logo-container {
    flex: 1;
}
.logo {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 5px;
}
nav {
    flex: 2;
}
.nav-links {
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-link {
    color: #5f5f79;
    font-size: 112%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I hope you can help me :) It would be great if the visitors could open the header through a burger icon...

Comment: We can't make just 'make something responsive' as we would need to know what you want it to look like, and how it should behave in the transition. That being said, you should use CSS Media Queries to do what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can simply use bootstrap to make it responsive.
Following is the code for adding the bootstrap.

**You simply need to add the link and scripts in your head.**

```
<head>

<title>Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
```

**Code for Responsive Header:**

```
<div class="logo-container row">
    <img src="./img/logo.svg" class="col-6" alt="logo" />
    <h4 class="logo col-6">CVaS</h4>
</div>
```

**And now the code for Responsive Navbar:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

**Note:** You won't need to add css style after this most likely.

If you don't want to use bootstrap then you can simply use media queries in css for different widths. You can make it responsive using position property in css along with media query.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use bootstrap, you should use `col-sm-[1 - 12]`, `col-md-[1 - 12]`, `col-lg-[1 - 12]` and `col-xl-[1 - 12] classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp this will be a great place to start if u just learning code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't make something responsive. You build it responsive in the first place. Start by styling it from mobile, tablet and desktop. Use the CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap (Free). Then for the menu area you may be best using something like the Navbar:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/

This will then swap to a hamburger menu on small screens (if you want).